which is similar to adversary condition and which to unexpected result in sentences containing although or but?
Suppose A and B are clauses.
Is the meaning of

A, although (or though) B.

closer to "A in spite that (or even if) B" or "B in spite that (or even if) A"?
Same question for the meaning of

A, but B.

I am looking for which of A and B is similar to "adversary condition" and which is like "unexpected result" in the two examples.
